# Trouble finding where in SFDC an outbound email is fired after checking a box on a UI page

Tags: trigger, email, fields

I currently have a checkbox which when True, sends an email. I want to change the Email address that this is sent to but I can't seem to find where this action is stored. I presumed it would be a Trigger, but it's not stored under the triggers section of the object. Neither does it seem to be an option on the field itself. Since I didn't set this up, I'm not sure where it is or how it was done.

Any ideas where it might be and how I might be able to find it?

Comment: did you take a look at the workflow rules ? Email alerts can be triggered from a work flow when there is a field update

Comment: @rao convert that one to an answer will ya ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you take a look at the workflow rules ? Email alerts can be triggered from a work flow when there is a field update